# text to Speech: read List and play audio file between headlines

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, audio, text-to-speech

i am using **dragon-dictations iPhone SDK Speech Kit** for *text to Speech* in my app.
i want to read the headlines in tableView.
i am getting the values from coreData and saving them to a textfile
(later, i want to do more with the textfile).

So between the headlines, i want to play a sound, like a **jingle, earcon or audio cue/audio file**, so the user gets notified with this sound, that the headline is changed.
I have no idea how to implement a function, to play a jingle between headlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution for my question is:

i have to use SSML. with ssml i can play a audiofile whereever i want.

this is the line for it:

```
<audio src="welcome.wav">
```

Answer (score 0):

for text to Speech u can use flite-1.4-iphone

- HOW TO USE

To use it in a new or existing project you can follow these steps:

0: Grab the latest version from http://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts/ and open it in finder.

1: Drag the "flite-1.4-iphone" directory into your project's "Other Sources" area.  This contains the sources to flite.

2: Drag the files FliteTTS.h and FliteTTS.m into your project's "Classes" area.

3: Add AVFoundation framework to your project if it does not already have it.

4: For the class where you want to call the library, if you want to define a class variable in the .h file,

add this line to your .h file just above the @interface line:

@class FliteTTS;

5: Create a pointer to the class, either in the .h or the .m depending on your needs:

```
FliteTTS *fliteEngine;
```

6: In the .m file for the class add...

## import "FliteTTS.h"

7: Initialize an FliteTTS object and point your pointer to it:

```
fliteEngine = [[FliteTTS alloc] init];
```

8: Start using it:

```
[fliteEngine speakText:@"It works."];   // Make it talk

[fliteEngine setPitch:100.0 variance:50.0 speed:1.0];// Change the voice properties

[fliteEngine setVoice:@"cmu_us_awb"];   // Switch to a different voice

[fliteEngine stopTalking];              // stop talking
```

- INCLUDED VOICES (you can remove the ones you don't need)

cmu_us_kal

cmu_us_kal16

cmu_us_awb

cmu_us_rms

cmu_us_slt

---

u can dowload sample code from [here](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/flite/)
http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/flite/

Comment: thank you for answering, but i am already using an SDK for **tts**. my problem is something different. i want to play an audiofile when spoken text is done and before new text starts to spoken.

Comment: thanks again, but i think you have misunderstood my question.